# Intento guardar en un fichero y un auxiliar los nombres, edad, etc. pero al compilar obtengo el error expected primary expression before '.' token

Tags: dev-c++

Soy muy novato y con fragmentos de código de unos ejemplos, intento crear un código que me permita guardar en ficheros la información de nadadores para una prueba de un competencia: *Nombre, edad, club, genero, tiempo previo, tiempo preliminar, tiempo final* que me permita añadir la cantidad de nadadores que desee y que me muestre cosas como los nombres de los nadadores inscritos y más. El problema lo encuentro nada más empezar a guardar nombres de los nadadores: supongo que tiene que ver algo con la forma de crear arreglos y ponerlos en ficheros. El problema surge desde que intento poner un tamaño al vector a través de una función que llamé *cantidaddenadadores*. No sé si eso sea posible, sino, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

/* */

struct nadadores
{
    int edad;
    char genero[10];
    char club[4];
    char nombre;
    float prminutos;
    float prsegundos;
    float prmilesimas;
    
    float prlminutos;
    float prlsegundos;
    float prlmilesimas;
    
    float fminutos;
    float fsegundos;
    float fmilesimas;
}registro,registro2;
float cantidaddenadadores(int x)
{
        struct nadadores
        nadadores[x];
        int i=0;
        float tiempos[x];
}

main()
{
    FILE *fichero;
    FILE *ficheroAux;
    int i=0;
    int opcion=0;
    float tiempopr;
    int x;
    printf("Bienvenido.\n");
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de nadadores que van a la competencia");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    cantidaddenadadores(x);
    while (opcion!=11)
    {
        printf("Seleccione la opcion que desea: \n\t");
        printf("1. Ingresar nombre.\n\t");
        printf("2. Ingresar edad.\n\t");
        printf("3. Ingresar genero.\n\t");
        printf("4. Ingresar club.\n\t");
        printf("5. Ingresar tiempo previo.\n\t");
        printf("6. Ingresar tiempo preliminar.\n\t");
        printf("7. Ingresar tiempo final.\n\t");
        printf("8. Mostrar nadadores inscritos.\n\t");
        printf("9. Mostrar resultados.\n\t");
        printf("10. Cambiar datos.\n\t");
        printf("11. Salir.\n\n");
        printf("Ingrese la opcion que desea");
        scanf("%d", &opcion);   
        if(opcion==1)
        {
            if ((fichero = fopen( "Informacion.txt", "w" )) == NULL)
            {
                printf( "No se puede abrir el fichero.\n" );
                exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
            fopen( "Informacion.txt", "w" );
            printf( "Nombre: " );
//*Aquí sale el primer error. intenté poner registro 2 y corchetes con el tamaño del array pero tampoco funcionó(ni esperaba que funcionara)//
            scanf("%c",&nadadores.nombre[25]);
//[Error]Expected primary expression before '.' token
            fwrite( &registro, sizeof(registro), 1, fichero);
            fclose(fichero);
            exit(1);
            }
        }
        else if(opcion==2)
        {
            printf("\nIngrese la edad del nadador: \n");
            printf( "edad: " );    
            scanf("%s",&registro.edad);
            fwrite( &registro, sizeof(registro), 1, fichero);
            fclose(fichero);
            break;
        }
        else if(opcion==3)
        {
            printf("\nIngrese el genero del nadador: \n");
            printf( "Genero: " );    
            scanf("%c",&registro.genero);                           
            fwrite( &registro, sizeof(registro), 1, fichero);
            fclose(fichero);
            break;
        }
        else if(opcion==4)
        {
            printf("\nIngrese el club del nadador: \n");
            printf( "club: " );    
            scanf(" %c",&registro.club);
            fwrite( &registro, sizeof(registro), 1, fichero);
            fclose(fichero);
            break;
        }
        else if(opcion==5)
        {
            float minutos,segundos, milesimas;
            printf("\nIngrese el tiempo EN MINUTOS previo del nadador: \n");
            printf( "Tiempo Previo minutos: " );    
            scanf("%f",&registro.prminutos);       
            printf("\nIngrese el tiempo EN SEGUNDOS previo del nadador: \n");
            printf( "Tiempo Previo minutos: " );    
            scanf("%f",&registro.prsegundos);    
            printf("\nIngrese el tiempo EN MILESIMAS previo del nadador: \n");
            printf( "Tiempo Previo minutos: " );    
            scanf("%f",&registro.prmilesimas);
            fwrite( &registro, sizeof(registro), 3, fichero);
            fclose(fichero);
            break;
        }
        else if(opcion==6)
        {
            float minutos,segundos, milesimas;
            printf("\nIngrese el tiempo EN MINUTOS preliminar del nadador: \n");
            printf( "Tiempo Previo minutos: " );    
            scanf("%f",&registro.prlminutos);
            printf("\nIngrese el tiempo EN SEGUNDOS preliminar del nadador: \n");
            printf( "Tiempo Previo minutos: " );    
            scanf("%f",&registro.prlsegundos);
            printf("\nIngrese el tiempo EN MILESIMAS preliminar del nadador: \n");
            printf( "Tiempo Previo minutos: " );    
            scanf("%f",&registro.prlmilesimas);
            fwrite( &registro, sizeof(registro), 3, fichero);
            fclose(fichero);
            break;
        }
        else if(opcion==7)
        {
            float minutos,segundos, milesimas;
            printf("\nIngrese el tiempo EN MINUTOS final del nadador: \n");
            printf( "Tiempo Previo minutos: " );    
            scanf("%f",&registro.fminutos);   
            printf("\nIngrese el tiempo EN SEGUNDOS final del nadador: \n");
            printf( "Tiempo Previo minutos: " );    
            scanf("%f",&registro.fsegundos);
            printf("\nIngrese el tiempo EN MILESIMAS final del nadador: \n");
            printf( "Tiempo Previo minutos: " );    
            scanf("%f",&registro.fmilesimas);
            fwrite( &registro, sizeof(registro), 3, fichero);
            fclose(fichero);
            break;
        }   
        else if(opcion==8)
        {
            if((fichero = fopen( "Informacion.txt", "r" )) == NULL)
            {
                printf( "No se puede abrir el fichero.\n" );
                exit( 1 );
            }
            else
            {
                while (feof(fichero)==0)
                {
                    while (fread(&registro2, sizeof(registro2), 1, fichero) == 1)
                    {
                        printf( "\nEl nadador 1 %d es: %s\n",i,registro2.nombre);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                fclose(fichero);
                i=0;
            }
        system("pause");
        break;
        }

}
```

Comment: Sería de ayuda si compartieras el error completo. Entre otras cosas, puede mencionar la línea en la que se encuentra.

Comment: El `%c` indica `un solo carácter y estás pasando una cadena de caracteres. Utiliza `%s`y quítale el `&` y `[25]` por . Utiliza `%25s`. Pero el error es porque estás utilizando "nadadores" que es la estructura debiendo ser `registro`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Tienes error en la declaracion del **struct**. Los **struct** se declaran `struct{ /* Escribes tus atributos aqui */ } nombre_del_struct`; ,o puedes poner el nombre despues de la palabra struct, pero lo que si no puedes hacer es poner nombre delante y despues de la declaracion de atributos como lo has hecho.

Aqui te dejo como referencia el libro conocido como la biblia de C, del creador del lenguaje: [El Lenguaje de Programacion C](https://frrq.cvg.utn.edu.ar/pluginfile.php/13741/mod_resource/content/0/El-lenguaje-de-programacion-C-2-ed-kernighan-amp-ritchie.pdf), en el capitulo 6 encontraras los Structs y podras auxiliarte mejor.

2. Sugiero cambiar los atributos del struct (genero, club, nombre) a string ya que no veo que hagas nada con ningun caracter especifico. Si lo haces debes incluir `#include <string.h>`
3. Tienes una funcion non-void que no retorna nada, si la funcion ***cantidaddenadadores*** no devuelve ningun parametro te sugiero que cambies su tipo de **float** a **void**. Revisa el codigo y corrigelo porque no se entiende que quieres hacer en la funcion.
4. Las funciones en c y c++ llevan el tipo delante por lo que da error que no se lo pongas a la funcion **main()** (*int main()*).
5. En la linea 74: `scanf("%c",&nadadores.nombre[25]);` , debes cambiar '%c' por '%s' ya que estas imprimiendo un string y no un char. Y corregir en la declaracion del atributo nombre ya que declaraste `char nombre`, eso significa que solo tiene un caracter y tu estas forzandolo a que tenga 25 por lo que entra en conflicto.
6. Te flata la llave que cierra el main.
7. Elimina la primera linea `#include <iostream>`, pues tu codigo no esta usando nada de esa libreria, lo usa de `#include <stdio.h>`.
8. Debes modificar tu menu en el main, pues permite entrar cualquier dato de un nadador sin tener que ingresar el nombre, que sentido tiene tener datos de alguien que no sabes quien es? Lo ideal es que le permitas al usuario poder ingresar todos los datos de un nadador de una sola vez y luego los guardas donde y/o como quieras.
   Otra cosa, sugiero que declares el fichero antes de hacer esas condicionales que tienes y lo cierras despues de haber ingresado todos los datos de los nadadores, el modo de declararlo inicialmente si el fichero seria `fichero = fopen( "Informacion.txt", "a" )`, puesto que el fichero debe estar crado y tener alguna informacion por lo que solo vas a agregar nuevos datos sin borrar los existentes. En el capitulo 7 del libro antes referenciado encontraras el manejo de entrada y salida (ficheros inclusive).
   Tambien sugiero que no pongas tantos `if/else`, utiliza el `switch` que se ve mejor esteticamente.

Revisa tu codigo de manera general y realiza correciones.
Espero que esto te ayude

Una manera es que antes del while (menu que tienes) abre el fichero, luego cuando el usuario ingrese los datos de los nadadores solo tienes que agregarlos al fichero y no abrirlo nuevamente como haces en cada opcion del menu. Ejemplo:

```
 fichero = fopen( "Informacion.txt", "a" );                               
 while(*condicion*){                                                      
    printf("Seleccione la opcion que desea: \n\t");                               
    printf("1. Ingresar datos de los nadadores.\n\t");                                        
    // debes crear una funcion para leer esos datos                                  
    printf("2. Cambiar datos.\n\t")                                                  
    printf("3. Mostrar resultados.\n\t");                                            
    printf("4. Salir.\n\n");    

   /* 
      Luego en la opcion 1 y 2 solo tienes que hacer un ***fwrite*** con 
      los datos y fuera del while haces ***fclose***  
   */                                                            
}
```

Comment: muy útil :) No me queda claro lo de "sugiero que declares el fichero antes de hacer esas condicionales que tienes y lo cierras despues de haber ingresado todos los datos de los nadadores, el modo de declararlo inicialmente si el fichero seria fichero = fopen( "Informacion.txt", "a" ), puesto que el fichero debe estar crado y tener alguna informacion por lo que solo vas a agregar nuevos datos sin borrar los existentes."